# ¿Como puedo actualizar 1 o varios archivo de código en diversas raspberr pi4 cuando ese archivo tenga una nueva version?

Tags: linux, redes, programación-bajo-nivel, arquitectura, devops

Todo lo descrito  se maneja en una red local

Son varios problemas

- Debo realizar configuraciones en las raspberry pi como: crear directorio, archivo y demonios con systemctl. Esto es para darle unas configuraciones.
- Debo actualizar 1 mismo archivos en todas las raspberry pi que forme parte de la red local, lo cual pueden ser 7 - 15 o más.
- Debo actualizar 1 misma base de datos en todas las rasberry pi

**¿Cómo lo estaba haciendo?
(El código lo desarrollo en mi computadora)
Rasbperry que me entregaban, les iba realizando las configuraciones pertinentes y subiendo el script que iban a utilizar, fue fácil cuando eran 3, pero poco a poco van a ser más, pero el problema con el que me tope fue al momento que yo realizar y actualizaba el código que utilizan las raspberry pi, ya que tenia que ir 1 por 1 actualizando el código con la nueva versión, realizaba las revisiones pertinentes para asegurarme bien que había actualizado el script, pero poco a poco se van a ingresar más raspberrys a la pila y debo realizar los mismo para todas. Entonces la dificulta va a crecer a medida que sigan ingresando raspberrys a la pila del sistema, ya que si ahi una nueva versión del código debo ir actualizando cada rasbperry 1 por 1(Eso toma muchísimo tiempo).
Por otra parte, también esto se aplica que a la base de datos, ya que todas llevan la misma base de datos, sin embargo se realizan cambios en las tablas en la base de datos y debo hacer lo descrito arriba.**

He pensado en algunas soluciones automatizadas:

- Hacer un escáner de red local y todas las raspberry que encuentre, replicar los las nuevas actualizaciones o configuraciones a cada una mediante una conexión ssh automatizada con algún lenguaje de programación o hacer con script bash claro con un demonio.
- Estube investigando sobre docker como una opción para la solución pero esta en veremos.

Comment: El código, ¿son scripts o un ejecutable? ¿En cuál lenguaje esta hecho?. ¿Cuál motor de base de datos usas?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido a SO. Lo más elegante (aunque no lo más sencillo) es que puedas utilizar un repositorio (git?) del proyecto al que puedas empujar versiones *estables* en tu red local. Los raspi podrían estar verificando dicho repo cada tanto (un cronjob) y cuando hay una nueva versión hacer el proceso de update automágico (a partir de todo lo que está en la nueva versión). De esa forma evitas tener que estar actualizando cada una de ellas.

Esto es una descripción de la lógica a muuuuy grandes rasgos. Te vas a encontrar docenas de detalles que desentrañar en el camino.

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación, me has dado luz en el camino. Por cierto, vi la posibilidad de usar un servidor git a nivel local y tratar de implementarlo con los cronjob

Comment: A estas alturas la gente **asume** de entrada que para usar git hay que usar gitlat/github/algun-otro. No es el caso. Puedes montar repositorios básicamente en cualquier sitio bajo tu control (te puedo apostar que ni Google, ni Facebook, ni muchos otros tienen su precioso código que no quieren compartir en equipos de 3os).